# Как вернутся через ActionBar но не в активность, а в фрагмент

Tags: android

У меня есть активность и три фрагмента. Я пролистываю до нужного фрагмента и нажимаю на картинку, попадаю на экран запланированной активности. На ней есть кнопка "назад" которая отправляет назад к активности. И приходится снова пролистывать до того же фрагмента. Вот код того действия:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

А к активности возвращается потому что та описана в манифесте как родительская.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ManicureDetailActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

Нельзя ли указать возврат не к активности, а к тому же фрагменту от которого ушли?

Comment: Во первых у вас возвращает к главной активности не потому что вы прописали в манифесте данную активность главной, а потому что ваш код actionbar возвращает к активности которая главная `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` Для того что бы возвращатся назад, вам нужно использовать onBackPresed, в котором прописать, что ваш `actionBar.goBack();`  возвращается к предыдущему активити или фрагменту, в зависимости от того где вы находились

Comment: Я захотела вас проверить и укаэала другую активность в манифесте и... случилось чудо, все стало происходить как мне нужно))) Ну ладно, это конечно ошибка, но забавная))) По поводу onBackPresed, это же метод такой? У меня там .goBack() горит красненьким, что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` главная активность, которая прописана в манифесте. Какую активность вы укажите, такую `actionBar` и будет открывать.

Если нужно вернутся назад, а не к главной активности:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

А метод:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Или просто добавьте метод.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).